# spawn of Eventlet does not work. So strange

Tags: python, spawn, eventlet

**** hi,all

i am using eventlet to implement a web crawler. My code is just like this

```
import eventlet


urls = [
    "http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL%E6%95%99%E7%A8%8B",
    "http://www.google.com.hk",
    "http://www.baidu.com",
]



def fetch(url):
    print('entering fetch')
    body=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print('body')


pool = eventlet.GreenPool(100)
for url in urls:
    pool.spawn(fetch,url)
    time.sleep(10)
```

but it outputs nothing  and it seems that fetch does not run at all

BTW,pool.imap does works

what happened?

what i want to do is that：the urls are coming streamly ,i.e. one by one. just like this

```
While(True):
   url=getOneUrl() #get one url streamly
   pool.spawn(fetch,url) #fetch the url
```

but it does not work,either.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the eventlet implementation, the pool.imap code will wait until all greenthreads in the pool finish working, but pool.spawn won't and ends immediately.

You can try appending some waiting or sleeping at the end of you script. Then those spawned greenthreads will executed your function.

```
pool.waitall()
```

or

```
eventlet.sleep(10)
```

Actually, in 'for body in pool.imap(fetch, urls)', it calls pool.imap and iterate the results. The invoke of pool.imap doesn't call waiting functions, but the iterating does.

Try doing it without iteration of the result. Without iteration, it ends immediately as pool.spawn.

```
pool = eventlet.GreenPool(100)
pool.imap(fetch, urls)
```

If you want to know more about this, just check the code in greenpool.py.

---

There is only one thread running for all green threads. Try this on all green threads, you will get a unique thread id.

```
print greenthread.getcurrent(), threading.current_thread()
```

If looping without eventlet.sleep, the thread is blocked all the time. Other green threads have no chance to be scheduled. So one possible solution for your problem is calling eventlet.sleep after invoking spawn in your while loop.

Comment: thanks very much for your reply.But my problem is that the urls should be downloaded are coming streamly....i.e one by one.just like this while(True)： url=getOneUrl;fetch(url) how to implement it via spawn or imap ? thanks a lot

Comment: thanks a lot .you are so nice.i found that you reedit your poster again and again .really appreciate it .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at my crawler using Eventlet: https://github.com/temoto/heroshi/blob/3b5e273783de9ea4b24cbcb0bf01a5025f653b93/heroshi/worker/Crawler.py

You received an excellent response from Yuan, I would only like to add two things:

- `time.sleep()` without monkey patching will block the whole process and no URLs will be fetched. Either run `eventlet.monkey_patch()` at the start or use `eventlet.sleep()`.
- On streaming URLs, again you may want to just use io-worker from Heroshi master. It's an independent program that reads URLs from stdin, crawls them and writes results to stdout. If you really want to use Eventlet for it, use shared Queue, it works:

---

```
pool = eventlet.GreenPool(100)
urls = eventlet.queue.Queue()
results = eventlet.queue.Queue()

urls.put('http://seed-url-1')
urls.put('http://seed-url-2')
# ...


def fetch(url):
  # ...
  results.put(...)


def crawl():
  while True:  # this is not C/Java, you don't need parens
    url = urls.get()
    pool.spawn(fetch, url)


def parse():
  while True:
    result = results.get()
    # ...
    urls.put(new_url_from_page)


eventlet.spawn(crawl)
eventlet.spawn(parse)
```